# Visual Studio 2010 logging

Tags: visual-studio-2010, logging

I am trying to create the ActivityLog for visual studio 2010 (as it freezes periodically for about 15-20 secs), so in a DOS box I entered:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE>devenv.exe /log
```

It is my understanding that this will create the visual studio log files under:

```
C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0
```

(NOTE: I am running windows 7 professional). However the logging files are not being created.

I will appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: try to open visual studio using admin account, as you might not have sufficient permissions right now

Comment: Thanks rajansoft1. Do you know how can i tell to run with administratives rightsvia the command prompt ? I can't find an option for that http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7.aspx .An even though my account is part of the administrators group i always have to run as administrator when initializing VS via shortcut

Comment: right click on visual studio and click on run as admin

Comment: I think we are going in circles here. If i do a right click on visual studio run as admin what happens with the logging? In order to create the visual studio logs i need to start VS from within a command prompt with the /log switch